# Как сделать скриншоты страниц с помощью php?

Tags: doc, php

Как сделать скриншоты страниц с помощью php документов формата doc?
На [данном](http://rus.atlants.lv/referat/antropomorfas-un-zoomorfas-figuras-un-teli/861244/) сайте это реализовано.

у меня есть документ в формате doc и я хочу сделать препросмотр страниц у себя на сайте в виде картинок для того что бы можно было увидеть примерную структуру данного документа, так так документ платный а продовать надо.

Comment: С помощью PHP? Вы хотите на стороне сервера или клиента? А почему просто не открыть страницу в браузере и снять с него скриншот локально?

Comment: человек не совсем верно выразился:) у него есть документ в формате doc и он хочет сделать препросмотр страниц у себя на сайте в виде картинок (по принципу "око видит, а мышка не выделяет").

Думается мне, что в этом случае наиболее правильно будет сделать просто печать документа на виртуальный принтер и в результате получить пачку картинок. А оторбразить их - не проблема.

Comment: я бы посмотрел в сторону php pdf

есть сервисы, которые апи предоставляют. вот например: http://www.convertapi.com/

Comment: ну так мы и предлагаем посмотреть на php pdf, на его основе генерить картинки из живого doc файла.

Answer (score 3):

Посмотрите на [phpLiveDocx](http://www.phplivedocx.org/) — точно [умеет конвертировать doc в pdf](http://www.phplivedocx.org/2009/02/06/convert-doc-to-pdf-in-php/), может, и в битмэповые превью тоже.